# multithreading Java cannot fully use all the OS cores on Windows

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, ubuntu, jvm

I have two machines with exactly the same hardware settings: **Intel i7 CPU (4 cores, 8 threads or virtual cores) 16GB memory**. The only difference is that one machine runs Windows 7, and the other hosts Ubuntu.

My multi-threading program has 8 threads doing similar tasks. I noticed that when it is running on the windows machine, only 4 virtual cores are running with 30% CPU usage, and the rest 4 virtual cores have 0 CPU usage. When the same program runs on the Ubuntu machine, all the 8 virtual cores have roughly equal CPU usage of 30%.

Besides, the program runs significantly faster on the Ubuntu machine.

Why does java not use all the CPU cores on windows? Is there anything particular with the jre/OS setting?

More details on System info:

- Windows 7 64 bit, Oracle 64 bit java 1.7
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit, OpenJDK 64 bit java 1.7

More details on the task:

- One thread read file, initiate instances, feed them to input buffer (LinkedBlockingQueue).
- Eight threads calculate some measures for each given instances. The calculation results are fed to output buffer (LinkedBlockingQueue).
- One thread write the results to file (sort of intensive I/O here).

Comment: Not enough information to give an answer.  If your CPUs (even in Ubuntu) are only running at 30% then your threads are not CPU-bound, meaning they're waiting on some other resource.  Access to that resource may behave differently in different OSes.  Each OS also schedules threads differently, etc., not to mention there may be minor differences between Oracle and open-source versions of the JDK.

Comment: @WilliamPrice That's a solid point. I am curious is there any jvm/OS settings that specify the number of threads a program can use.

Comment: There are OS tools that can be used to set _processor affinity_, but unless you've used them I'm quite confident that Java knows how many physical threads are available on the machine and that the OS will allow Java to use them all.  You list lots of potentially blocking operations (file I/O, blocking queues) not to mention there's a possibility of starvation with one reader and eight workers -- you're probably seeing thread scheduling differences between the OSes.  Does Windows actually run slower?  If not, don't worry about how the OS reports CPU usage.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the HyperThreading can cause contention between the fake "cores" in each real core, and it's quite common for the OS not to overschedule the physical cores.

Comment: disable hyper-threading on both machines (it doesnt increase performance significantly  anyway) and then compare the execution speed.

Comment: you should use a profiler and see what's blocking the 8 compute threads. It sounds like they should be CPU-bound but aren't. Using `LinkedTransferQueue` instead of `LinkedBlockingQueue` can eliminate one source of thread suspension, at the risk of OOMEs.